# SSRS - Expression to count the rows for currentdate match or (parameter selected date) with some equivalent other columns

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, report-builder2.0

In SSRS Expression, how to count the numbers of rows that present in today or yesterday in dataset  with other equivalent condition,

For example

```
=COUNT(IIF(
    DateDiff(DateInterval.Day,Cdate("01/01/1900"),Fields!Opendate.Value) = 
    DateDiff(DateInterval.Day,Cdate("01/01/1900"), Now()), Fields!Opendate.Value, Nothing))
```

Using this expression I can check get the total count for today, it's working.

I need to add to check today date with other condition like:

```
If (today date and Fields!reason.Value = "Other")
```

It's not working when I add reason value to check :

```
=COUNT(IIF(
     DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, Cdate("01/01/1900"), Fields!Opendate.Value) = 
     DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, Cdate("01/01/1900"), Now()) -1, Fields!Opendate.Value, Nothing ) **And Fields!reason.Value = "Other"**)
```

Please guide me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add it in your `IIF()` statement:

```
=COUNT(IIF(
           DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, Cdate("01/01/1900"), Fields!Opendate.Value) = 
           DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, Cdate("01/01/1900") 
           And Fields!reason.Value = "Other",
           Now()) -1,
           Fields!Opendate.Value,
           Nothing 
           )
        )
```